# How do I use the BindingNavigator to add entries to my table and save?

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, binding, bindingnavigator

First some explanation:

I am attempting to make (what should be) a simple **offline** "character generator" for a game I am working on. I am using VB for this and I am still a beginner. I have created a WinForms application in VS 2012 and created a local database object to hold various data. Within the database I have a 'Players' table to hold all the data. I have also added a BindingNavigator to the form, yet I removed all but the add and delete buttons as navigation is controlled by a List control which is bound to the PlayersBindingSource. I also added a save button to the BindingNavigator.

I manually populated the 'Players' table with two example entries to work with and, when the form loads, the listBox displays the two entries by their 'Player Name' field correctly. When one is selected all the controls representing each field change accordingly. If I change any values and hit the save button, it *seems* to work with the code I'm using.

Now the problems:

When the add button is pressed, it makes a new entry in the ListBox, yet none of the default values specified are showing up. If I edit this entry and then hit save it seems to update fine. However, if I make any other changes to any of the entries and try to save, it throws an exception.

When the delete button is pressed, the entry disappears from the list as expected, but again, if I try to save, I get an exception.

here is the code that is in my form thus far (not much):

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PlayersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatPlayerDataSet.Players)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripButton.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PlayersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DatPlayerDataSet)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, if I look at the data contained in the 'Players' table, the two example entries remain unchanged, and no additional entries are added, so I don't think the edits were never actually committed to the table.

If anyone can help me with this, or could even simply provide a link to some tutorials that would help me, I would be highly appreciative. I have browsed this site, and microsofts msdn library, searching for information about data binding and navigation, yet I couldn't seem to find anything that helped.

Comment: I should also mention that I'm not using Entity Framework as far as I can tell.

Also, I need to add a copy button to copy the selected entry, and a print button that will send all the data to the printer, but that is for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You want do one more think in "btnNewPlayer_Click" sub after insert row, clear the list and re load the list items or call the function which you are using to fill the list items.

Comment: I got the new entry to show up now. I just had to use the BindingNavigator control. Now I'm just having issues with saving my edits. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -1):

Try refreshing the page, the list might get updated.

Comment: This is a stand-alone offline application. There's no page to refresh.